# MediaElementPlayer: Why can't I access a property of an object created outside of a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code:

```
var player = {};

$(document).ready(function() {
  initPlayer();
  initControls();
}

function initPlayer() {
  player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player', {
    loop: false,
    features: ['progress','duration','fullscreen'],
    success: function (mediaElement, domObject) { 
        mediaElement.addEventListener('pause', function(e) {
            $('#btn-play').find('span').toggleClass("glyphicon-pause").toggleClass("glyphicon-play");
        }, false);

        mediaElement.addEventListener('play', function(e) {
            $('#btn-play').find('span').toggleClass("glyphicon-play").toggleClass("glyphicon-pause");
        }, false);
    }
  });
}

function initControls() {
  $('#btn-play').click(function() {
      console.log(player.paused);
  }
}
```

I've created the empty '**player**' object outside the initPlayer function because I wanna use it later in different locations. The problem is, that I have no access to the properties of the object, outside of the **initPlayer** function.
The console.log in **initControls()** just throws an undefined.

When I define the player variable inside the initPlayer function (var player = new MediaElementPlayer [...]) I CAN read the properties of it in the initControls() function. Why do I have access to the local variable but not the global one?

Comment: Let's try `console.log(player);` What do you get?

Comment: I get: [object Object]. But when I define the variable within the initPlayer function I get: [object HTMLVideoElement]

Comment: It seems, in `initControls` there is only the `var player = {};` not the newly created `new MediaElementPlayer`. Try to change `var player = null;` and do the 2 `console.log` again. Tell me the results.

Comment: Same results, the `player` variable is `object Object` and the `player.paused` parameter is `undefined`.